# JSF2 AJAX issue with h:selectBooleanCheckbox

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

**Version :**

RichFaces 4.3.5

Apache MyFaces 2.1

**Issue :**

As shown in below code , I am facing below issue for `h:selectBoolenCheckbox` used within one of the columns of the `rich:dataTable.`

1)When multiple check boxes are checked one by one with a considerable delay between clicks , there is no issue .
Check boxes get clicked.

2)But when checkboxes are clicked with no delay , not all checkboxes are selected. If two checkboxes are selected very fast , only first one selected.
 After debuuing this issue , it is found that the second request doesn't call setter method of the required object keeping its value as false only.

My questions are  :

1)Why is second request doesn't call setter method of the object ? It is because first request processing is still not completed ?

2)How can this issue be resolved ? I have tried using  `immediate="true"` but no success.
Using java script may be the option.
But there is complex logic involved when a checkbox is selected , some checkboxes will be selected and disabled automatically depending on 
the value of currently selected check box.

This logic is handled in `app.value` getter method.

**Code :**

Listing 1 :

```
<h:panelGroup id ="panel">
  <rich:dataTable id="apps" value="#{bean.apps}" var="app">

       <!-- other columns not shown --> 

    <h:column>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="admin" disabled="#{app.disabled}" value="#{app.value}">
            <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="panel">
                        </a4j:ajax> 
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </h:column>             


  </rich:dataTable>
</<h:panelGroup>
```

**EDIT 1:**
Adding pseudo code of `app.getValue` :

```
public boolean getValue(){

    if(check other instance variable value){
        this.setValue(true);    
    }

}
```

Comment: Try implementing the logic of `app.value` in an ajax listener. Can you share the code of `app.value`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Updated the question with pseudo code

Comment: According to my understanding, your `if` condition is not letting you select multiple check boxes simultaneously!

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question , for the second request app.setValue is not getting called. So if condition is not the issue here it seems

Comment: did you try adding an ajax listener to `<a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="panel"/>`?

Comment: I am able to solve this issue by following trick. After clicking the check box , back end method is called but the page is NOT re-rendered after ajax request completes . This saves the time and second requests gets through successfully. This can be done where there is no re-rendering required for check boxes

Comment: Good!  
I'd suggest you to write an answer so that this may be helpful for others in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue by following trick. After clicking the check box , back end method is called but the page is NOT re-rendered after ajax request completes . This saves the time and second requests gets through successfully. This can be done where there is no re-rendering required for check boxes.

Following is the code which worked.

```
 <h:column>
        <!-- don't reRender -->
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="admin" disabled="#{app.disabled}" value="#{app.value}"
         rendered="#{not app.reRender}">
            <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this">
                        </a4j:ajax> 
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

         <!-- reRender -->
         <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="admin" disabled="#{app.disabled}" value="{app.value}"
        rendered="#{app.reRender}">
            <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@this" render="panel">
                        </a4j:ajax> 
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </h:column>
```